# Conexión JMS a queue remota de Weblogic

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

¡Buen día a todos!

Me encuentro dando mantenimiento a proyecto que hace uso de un archivo de contexto de Spring, la verdad es la primera vez que trabajo con este tipo de tecnologías. En fin el punto es que estoy tratando de implementar una conexión a una cola remota de Weblogic, cuando hago uso de las anotaciones de spring, lo puedo hacer sin ningún problema, pero cuando intento realizar esta conexión a través del uso de contextos, tengo el siguiente error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[weblogic, Administrators]
>           at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:309)
>           at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:555)
>           at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:313)
>           at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEConnectionFactoryImpl_12210_WLStub.connectionCreateRequest(Unknown Source)
>           at weblogic.jms.client.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:399)

En realidad no se si es un problema de seguridad, (aunque ese sea el error que me marque) porque como lo mencioné, ya he hecho este tipo de conexiones a través de anotaciones. Quiero creer que el problema esta en la implementación de mi archivo de contextos.

```
 <bean id="wlMessageSenderRemote"
     class="com.serviceplatform.example.jms.WLMessageSenderRemote">
    <property name="wlMessageSenderRemote">
        <ref bean="jmsTemplate" />
    </property>
  </bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref bean="connectionFactoryProxy" />
    </property>
    <property name="destinationResolver">
        <ref bean="jmsDestinationResolver" />
    </property>
    <property name="receiveTimeout">
        <value>50000</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!--Este es el bean donde no estoy segura de la implentación, pero igual trate eliminandolo y pasando el  bean "jndiTemplateRemote" directamente en el bean "jmsTemplate" y obtuve el mismo error-->
<bean id="connectionFactoryProxy"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="jndiTemplateRemote" />
</bean>

<bean id="jndiTemplateRemote"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>${example.example.wl.remote.jndi.name}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface"
        value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsDestinationResolver"
    class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
    </property>
    <property name="cache">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jndiTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${example.example.example.wl.remote.factory.initial}
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${example.example.example.wl.remote.provider.url}
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${example.example.example.wl.remote.credential.username}
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${example.example.example.wl.remote.credential.password}
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

> En este archivo de beans también tengo conexiones remotas a queues de tipo MQ. Estas conexiones si funcionan.

Esta es la clase en la que me estoy basando para hacer la implementación en beans y es con la que ya he logrado hacer la conexión a la queue remota:

```
/**
* Clase de configuracion.
*/
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class WLMessagingConfiguration {

/**
 * bean que extrae la informacion del propertvi ies.
 */
@Autowired
CommonEnv commonEnv;

@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public JndiObjectFactoryBean connectionFactory() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();

    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(commonEnv.getProperty(Const.WL_JNDI));
    return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
    JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
    Properties jndiProps = new Properties();

    jndiProps.setProperty(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, commonEnv.getProperty(Const.WL_FACTORY));
    jndiProps.setProperty(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, commonEnv.getProperty(Const.WL_PROVIDER));
    jndiProps.setProperty(InitialContext.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, commonEnv.getProperty(Const.WL_USERNAME));
    jndiProps.setProperty(InitialContext.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, commonEnv.getProperty(Const.WL_PASSWORD));
    jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(jndiProps);
    return jndiTemplate;
}

@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy connectionFactoryProxy() {
    return new TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy((ConnectionFactory) connectionFactory().getObject());
}


@Bean(name = "wlJmsTemplate")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryProxy());
    JndiDestinationResolver destinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();
    destinationResolver.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
    destinationResolver.setCache(true);

    template.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver);

    template.setReceiveTimeout(50000);
    return template;
}

@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryProxy());
    factory.setConcurrency(commonEnv.getProperty(Const.WL_CONCURRENCY));
    JndiDestinationResolver destinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();
    destinationResolver.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
    destinationResolver.setCache(true);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver);
    return factory;
}

}
```

La verdad ya he estado investigando por todos lados, y la información que encuentro es similar a lo que tengo, pero por más vuelta que le he dado no logro solucionarlo. Si alguien a tenido este tipo de situaciones, le agradecería si pudiera ayudarme.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Hola @YSCGProJ ¿Ya incluiste el paquete o en su defecto la clase en el **<context:component-scan base-package="paquete o clase especifica" />**?

Comment: Hola @DarthVader, no entiendo bien a que te refieres. Pero verás realice algunas modificaciones y ahora tengo un error diferente:  [ERROR] , org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jms.TestConnnectionFactory' didn't find subcontext 'jms'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jms/TestConnnectionFactory'
Tal vez puedas ayudarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de varios días obteniendo diferentes errores, me dí cuenta que en realidad si es un problema de "seguridad", bueno en realidad la solución que obtuve fue:

1. Borrar y crear el módulo JMS donde realice mi configuración para el servio JMS remoto.
2. Reiniciar por completo el dominio de Weblogic Server donde tengo montados mis componentes.

Adicional a esto es importante mencionar que cambié este bean de la siguiente manera.

**Antes:**

```
<bean id="jndiTemplateRemote"
   class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
   <property name="jndiName">
    <value>${example.example.wl.remote.jndi.name}</value>
   </property>
   <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
   <property name="proxyInterface"
      value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" /> 
</bean>
```

**Después**

```
<bean id="jndiTemplateRemote"
   class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
   <property name="jndiName">
       <value>${example.example.wl.remote.jndi.name}</value>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Una vez realizado esto, resulto posible depositar en la queue remota Weblogic.